# Keep text delimiters after !!str "some text" or !!str 'some text'

Tags: yaml

I have some data to be used to generate SQL, therefore it is important which text delimiters are used (single quotes ' delimits string literal but double quotes " delimit identifiers, at least in Oracle db).

For load procedure generator I used this

```
someKey: !!str 'Some SQL text'
```

and expected that someKey would contain the whole string including single quotes: `'Some SQL text'`.

However, js-yaml.safeLoad() interprets the data as `Some SQL text` which is not what I wanted.

The workaround is easy, I can put the literal into additional quotes:

```
someKey: "'Some SQL text'"
```

which gives the expected result.  However, I am not quite sure why in that case do we need !!str tag in YAML if it does virtually nothing (it is useful only for explicit interpretation number literals, true, false and null) and it is actually almost the same as putting double quotes around the text.

I would prefer to post this into some YAML-spec-related forum but it seems there is none.

Apart from the standard workaround, is there any trick that would do what I originally wanted, i.e. interpret any content after object key as string (+trimming off any initial and trailing spaces) without dealing with double quotes?

Comment: The reason why I need this:

Comment: The reason why I need this:
 - the object key is a name of an output column (alias)
 - the value represents expression to be assigned to this column.
Now, construction like this:
     column: 'FULL'
means that I want to asign string constant `FULL` to the column `column` while 
     column: FULL
should be interpreted as "assign value of identifier FULL to column `column`" - where FULL may be column, variable, function, etc.

Unfortunately the YAML spec interprets both of these as **FULL** which is in some sense loss of information, in this case a significant one.

Comment: There is a yaml mailing list and please note that [so] is not a forum but a Q&A site.

Comment: Who says that you need the `!!str`? Did you read the specification or just some secondary YAML-how-to that is not the real thing?

Comment: @Anthon, I indeed acknowledge that StackOverflow is not exactly the place for this type od question. On the other hand, I was looking for a yaml forum through Google and other search engines and found exactly zero forums.  I quit using mailing lists more than ten years ago because from a mailing list I usually get zero to one useful answer and then have to accept months or years of information I have not been looking for (to put it mildly).  Forum would be great if some existed. Mailing list - nope.  I don't have only YAML to deal with. And just one man to read all the mail.

Comment: I was not targeting specifically !!str, I was looking for some kind of markup or designator to interpret the content as string and not use the qutes to determine it is a string.

Comment: Well, and if you read YAML1.2 spec for the first time, you will find out it has 268 occurrences of "!!str" and 0 occurrences of "!!str tag", so when I was looking for some explanation of what exactly !!str is supposed to be doing I was not able to find it.  I realized by a practical test that js-yaml strips off the quotation marks, confirmed that in the online YAML parser and thus realized this behavior is compliant with spec. But not by reading the spec...

Comment: I think custom tag should do the same service. I think I actually need to find out how to extend the parser to interpret the custom tag. Is this the right approach?

Comment: If you use a custom tag would certainly work in Python, as it allows you to take special action in its representation as a string. I.e. the object creation gets a scalar string as value (without any unescaped leading/trailing quotes) and when you hand it as string to SQL you add the quotes. That should be doable in JavaScript  as well (I am taking a hint from `js-yaml` in your text here), I am just not familiar with its parsers.

Comment: These kind of questions are perfectly fine here IMO. Just post a follow up question that you tag with [tag:yaml], [tag:javascript] and/or [tag:js-yam] and ask how to define an new object that you can create based on a new tag and that when created to a string gets single quotes added before and after

Answer (score 4):

In YAML tag `!!str` is a predifened denoting a string scalar. If you specify that then even things that without that tag (or without quotes) would not be considered a string scalar, like `123`, `True` or `null`.

Some string scalars need quotes e.g. if they start with a quote or double quote, if special characters need backslash espacing, or if there is a `:` (colon, space) in the string (which could confuse the parser to intrepret the string scalar as a key-value pair.

However putting `!!str` before something doesn't make it quoted (which should be obvious as it doesn't define what kind of quoting and single quoted scalars have vastly different rules from double quoted scalars).

Your workaround is not a workaround, that is just one of the ways in YAML you can specify a string scalar that starts and ends with a single quote. Another way is:

```
someKey: |-
   'Some SQL text'
```

Within literal block style scalars quotes (single or double) are interpreted as is even at the beginning of the scalar. The `-` makes sure you don't get an extra newline after the final `'`